# Django-sorting Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Use django-sorting library according to this example:
[django-sorting example](https://github.com/directeur/django-sorting/wiki/example-usage), but get errors said "**Cannot reorder a query once a slice has been taken.**" at line "{% autosort object_list %}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slice is something like `object_list = MyModel.objects.all()[:5]`. Trying to autosort that would throw this error.

You'll need to pass an entire queryset to autosort.

Comment: Thanks, but I used the entire object_list, not slice.

Comment: @HaoweiCheng Can you include the source in your question?

Comment: @ TankorSmash I fixed this bug, because there is a pagination process in my view, i comment this, then works, but another problem is coming, there are so many data displayed in one page without pagination. how does this django-sorting handle the issue of pagination? Thanks,

Comment: @HaoweiCheng you'll have to open a new question with all the details and the code.

Comment: @TankorSmash I need to slice then reorder. How can I do that?

Comment: @keramat you'll have to open a new question so people can help you